# How do I fix this R code for area under curve?

Tags: r, polygon

I have code that is supposed to find the area under the normal but it ends up shading a triangle of the area rather than the full area from -2 to 0.8. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

```
curve(dnorm(x), xlim = c(-2, 2), ylab = "", axes = FALSE)
abline(h = 0)
sequence = seq(-2, 0.8)
polygon(x = c(sequence, 0.8, -2), y = c(dnorm(c(sequence)), 0, 0), col = "purple")
axis(1, at = c(-2, -1, 0, 0.8, 1, 2), pos = 0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have enough points in `sequence`. You can add more using:

```
sequence = seq(-2, 0.8, by = 0.1)
```

The smaller you make the step between points, the better the shaded area will match the curve.